# Extracting share count from AddThis button with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, addthis

Is there a another way to do this. If I remove display:none (which i don't want to do) it works but not all the time.

I'm trying to get the share count from the addthis widget, that will be in a hidden area on my site and output that count in another element.

http://jsfiddle.net/agileapricot/TpV28/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$("#addthis_counter").text();
```

by

```
$("#addthis_counter").html();
```

Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the contents of the counter element by with the

```
html()
```

function and

```
split(" ")[1];
```

the string to get what you want.